# Use reflection to get instances of static instances of derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.reflection

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I'm not overly familiar with Reflection so I'm not sure of the exact terms I should be searching for.

Basically I'm trying to find a list of defined public static fields for classes based on a type.

So given the class LocalisationToken I have a number of classes based on this, eg, AboutToken, AdminToken, etc.

Each of these classes has public static readonly instances of these derived classes, eg,:

```
public static readonly LocalisationToken TermsAndConditions = new AboutToken("Terms And Conditions", Guid.Parse("595FB313-4940-489b-9CC8-4B9BF0B62E8B"));
public static readonly LocalisationToken OkGotIt = new AboutToken("OK, got it", Guid.Parse("5F5F22A4-C45C-43f0-A2A4-304740E0EE12"));
```

What I would like to do is find all instances in a compiled library at run time. The underlying code when instantiating an AboutToken, say, is to create a new LocalisationToken using the constructor properties. My requirement is to get the Guid and default text back, eg, "Terms and Conditions" and 595FB313-4940-489b-9CC8-4B9BF0B62E8B

If I use GetTypes() on the assembly containing LocalisationToken, I just get the various derived classes of AboutToken, AdminToken, etc. I need the actual instances instead.

As it happens, I don't need the derived classes at all. But would I need to iterate through those, even if all instances are marked as "LocalisationTokens"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's important to understand that it's the *field* which is static - not the *instance*.

You can easily find readonly static fields though, and fetch their values. For example:

```
var someAssembly = typeof(Foo).Assembly; // Or whatever
var values = from type in someAssembly.GetTypes()
             from field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static |
                                          BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic)
             where field.IsInitOnly &&
                   field.FieldType == typeof(LocalisationToken)
             select (LocalisationToken) field.GetValue(null);
```

Comment: `field.FieldType == typeof(LocalisationToken)` is always returning false for me. In debugging I can see that FieldType *appears* the same but the Equals method is always false. Not sure the best practice here; my particular app is just a dev tool so I'll probably match on `field.FieldType.FullName`.

Comment: @Ricket: That suggests you might have two `LocalisationToken` classes, in different assemblies (or differently *loaded* assemblies). It's hard to tell based on just that information - you might want to ask a new question with more details.